# Clojure comparing lines in file

Tags: file, hash, clojure, compare, lines

I have to write a clojure function, that compares lines in a file.
My file contains information like this:

```
{:something1 1
    :something2 2
    :something2 2
    :something3 3
    :something4 4
    :something4 4
}
```

You can see it is written to define a hash. I want to import the hash in my program, but before doing so, I need to remove every line that is equal to other line. My lines need to be unique. How can I do this?
I tried few things, but they were complete fails.

Comment: would your input contain duplicate keys, duplicate values, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defn read-map-wo-dups [fname]
  (into {}
   (with-open [r (reader fname)]
     (doall (distinct
             (map #(read-string
                    (str "[" (replace % #"[{}]" "") "]"))
                  (line-seq r)))))))
```

Test:

`data.dat` contains:

```
{:something1 1
 :something2 2
 :something2 2
 :something3 3
 :something3 3
 :something4 4}
```

result:

```
(read-map-wo-dups "data.dat")
=> {:something1 1, :something2 2, :something3 3, :something4 4}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are my hero. :)

Comment: @Wintre FYI I've removed unnecessary `trim`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be broken up into simpler steps then threaded into a simple "one-liner"

```
(->> (slurp "data")         ; read the data from the file.
     (re-seq #"[^{} \n]+")  ; split it into strings ignoring \n and { }.
     (partition 2)          ; group it into key, value pairs
     (map vec)              ; turn the pairs into vectors because into wants this.
     (into {}))             ; mash them in turn into a single map.

{":something1" "1", ":something2" "2", ":something3" "3", ":something4" "4"}
```

Or if you prefer the nested form, you can write the same code like this:

```
user> (into {} (map vec (partition 2 (re-seq #"[^{} \n]+" (slurp "data")))))
{":something1" "1", ":something2" "2", ":something3" "3", ":something4" "4"}
```

Comment: You've missed `(partition 2)` after `(re-seq...)` in the first solution.

Comment: I guess it's supposed to be keywords/numbers. So you need to `read` values too.

Comment: oops, mistake in editing dropped that line, thanks for noticing